# How to put image instead of text in h:commandLink value

Tags: image, jsf, commandlink

I have a command link as below.

```
<h:commandLink value="Home" action="homePage">
</h:commandLink>
```

This is working fine, but I need a image instead of text value. The image has to act as a command link.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @BalusC I am editing the post

Comment: So, I suppose you did something like this.   <h:commandLink  action="homePage">
      <h:graphicImage url="/images/bla.png" style="border:0"/>
     </h:commandLink>. What was the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove `value` attribute and put `<h:graphicImage>` inside `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<h:commandLink action="homePage">
    <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/img.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Initially I tried the above but I gave Image instead of value in Graphic image tag